# How To Combine Multiple Rows Into One Based on Shared Value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that generically looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Canada'], 'GDP':          [45000, 68000, 34000, 46000], 'Education': [5, 3, 7, 9]})
```

Giving:

```
    Country  Education    GDP
0     USA          5    45000
1     USA          3    68000
2  Canada          7    34000
3  Canada          9    46000
```

I'd like to have all the values for each country listed on the same row, so it reads:

```
Country    Education    Education    GDP        GDP
USA         5            3           45000      68000
```

How does one accomplish this?

And yes, some of the columns do have the same name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original DataFrame:

```
In [150]: df
Out[150]: 
  Country  Education    GDP
0     USA          5  45000
1     USA          3  68000
2  Canada          7  34000
3  Canada          9  46000
```

Given that [each country](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) will have exactly two values for the same attribute:

```
In [151]: df1 = df.groupby('Country').nth(0).reset_index()

In [152]: df1
Out[152]: 
  Country  Education    GDP
0  Canada          7  34000
1     USA          5  45000

In [153]: df2 = df.groupby('Country').nth(1).reset_index()

In [154]: df2
Out[154]: 
  Country  Education    GDP
0  Canada          9  46000
1     USA          3  68000
```

[Concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) the two data frames and [drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) duplicate column from any one:

```
In [155]: pd.concat([df1, df2.drop('Country', 1)], axis=1)
Out[155]: 
  Country  Education    GDP  Education    GDP
0  Canada          7  34000          9  46000
1     USA          5  45000          3  68000
```

Rearrange the columns, if needed:

```
In [165]: df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.drop('Country', 1)], axis=1)

In [166]: df3 = df3[['Country', 'Education', 'GDP']]

In [167]: df3
Out[167]: 
  Country  Education  Education    GDP    GDP
0  Canada          7          9  34000  46000
1     USA          5          3  45000  68000
```

Comment: This is very useful and I marked it as answered.  However I did have one question:  what is the purpose of using the reset_index() method?

Comment: @JonathanBechtel http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Answer (score 2):

The output that you want generally leads to loss of information.

```
Country    Education    Education    GDP        GDP
USA         5            3           45000      68000
```

In the above case you would need to keep track of which GDP column corresponds to which Education column.

If you are not adamant about keeping it in this form, you can form a pivot table:

```
df2=df.pivot(index='Country',columns='Education',values='GDP').reset_index()
```

This makes each unique value of the education as a column and the value of that column will be the corresponding GDP value.

```
Education Country        3        5        7        9
0          Canada      NaN      NaN  34000.0  46000.0
1             USA  68000.0  45000.0      NaN      NaN
```

A better looking output can be obtained by:

```
df2=df.pivot(index='Country',columns='Education',values='GDP').reset_index().set_index('Country')
```

which yields

```
Country        3           5         7            9
Canada                            34000.0       46000.0
USA         68000.0     45000.0
```

Comment: Thank you, the pivot you provided is exactly what I was looking for :)